# dir function finds xls not xlsx in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am using `dir()` function in Excel vba programming with filter as ".xls".

But I have input files with the extension both `".xls"` and `".xlsx"` which have to be picked up for the process.

In many systems the macro picks the `".xlsx"` and `".xls"` files even though the filter specified as `".xls"` in the macro.

But in some systems it picks up only `"xls"` files and not `".xlsx"` files.

Any specific reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't answer the question "why does this happen", but it is a workaround:

Use `".xls?"` or `".xls*"` as your `Dir` filter:

```
MyFile = Dir("*.xls?")
```

or

```
MyFile = Dir("*.xls*")
```

Comment: I think also his missing "*." in the file spec is not doing any good. I will bet that the difference between systems is a FAT32/NTFS difference in treatment of this somewhat wonky filename.