# Excel VBA Dir() default path?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working through an exercise that uses Dir() to find out whether a file exists in the current directory (i.e. the same directory as the workbook I'm using). The code given - and apparently working in the video example - is like this:

```
IsThere = (Dir("SomeFile.xlsx") <> "")
```

When I run this code, IsThere returns `False`. I can work around it by using:

```
IsThere = (Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\SomeFile.xlsx") <> "")
```

but I want to know why Dir isn't looking by default in the current directory as expected.

I'm struggling to find any relevant advice on this. Most of the examples I've found of how to use Dir() are with the file path specified so they don't really shed any light on my problem. The closest I've found is [this (obsolete) MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) which says that:

> To run correctly, the Dir function requires the Read and PathDiscovery flags of FileIOPermission to be granted to the executing code.

Trouble is, I don't really understand the linked advice in there on how to set PathDiscovery to 1.

As for StackOverflow, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107858/vba-dir-function-not-working-on-excel-2010) is probably the closest to my problem - although this uses a specified path, and I am **not** referencing a network location. I note that the *answer* to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534671/dir-function-finds-xls-not-xlsx-in-excel-vba) seems to presume that Dir() should work in the way expected i.e. with a simple filename and not a fully specified path.

Comment: The answer here is if you're testing for files in a specific location then include the path in the call to `Dir()` - eg do not use (e.g.) `Dir("test.xlsx")` but use `Dir("C:\Folder\Folder2\test.xlsx")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with whatever the host application thinks it's directory is. You can always find out what directory `Dir` will default to by calling the `CurDir` function:

```
Debug.Print CurDir$
```

If you need to change it, call `ChDir`:

```
Debug.Print CurDir$
Debug.Print Dir$("*.*")
ChDir "C:\"
Debug.Print CurDir$
Debug.Print Dir$("*.*")
```

Think of it like sitting at a command prompt and typing `dir` or `cd` - it does exactly the same thing.  Note that the current directory holds it's state between macro executions, so you can't rely on it being in some default location.

If you need a path relative to an open Workbook, use `Workbook.Path` if you need a path relative to the default path, use `Application.Path`. If you need to test for the existence of a file, don't use `Dir` at all - use the Scripting.FileSystemObject instead. You'll do yourself a huge favor if start thinking of the legacy file functions as deprecated.

Comment: Regarding FSO - that's fine as long as your code never needs to run on a Mac, but there's really nothing wrong with `Dir()`: it is certainly not "legacy"...

Comment: @TimWilliams - There's nothing *inherently* wrong with `Dir` once you get used to its idiosyncrasies, but the FSO is much more robust.  Maybe "legacy" isn't the best term - I use it in the sense of "existed long, long before a much better option became available".

Comment: Really clear, comprehensive answer - works like a charm - thank you!

Comment: Odd, because regardless of where I open a file from, `CurDir$` always returns the Excel Default File Location...until it is changed.  Which seem to make sense as that is going to be the first value of it.  And....changing the default file location changes `CurDir$`

Answer (score 0):

Check the Excel Options --> Save --> Default File location to see what your default is.  It won't by default use where the file is located.