# Count files in folder – Strange behaviour of Dir

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following function to count files of a certain file type `sFileType` in folder `sPath`.

```
Function CountFilesInFolder(sPath As String, Optional sFileType As String) As Long

    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim lFileCount As Long
    
    If Right(sPath, 1) <> "\" Then sPath = sPath & "\"
    vFile = Dir(sPath & sFileType)
    While (vFile <> "")
        lFileCount = lFileCount + 1
        vFile = Dir
    Wend
    
    CountFilesInFolder = lFileCount
End Function
```

When testing the function on a folder that contains:

- 2 `xls` files and
- 3 `xlsx` files

With

`Debug.Print CountFilesInFolder(“C:\test\”, “*.xls”)`

I would expect it to return `2`, however, the function is also counting the `xlsx` files and it returns `5`.

If I test the function

`Debug.Print CountFilesInFolder(“C:\test\”, “*.xlsx”)`

it returns 3, like expected. Why does the function in the first example also count the `xlsx` files? I am not specifying any wildcard, but still `Dir` behaves like it. Am I doing something wrong here? I could probably add an `If` statement in the `While/Wend`, but I assume I am doing something wrong with the `Dir` function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dir function finds xls not xlsx in excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534671/dir-function-finds-xls-not-xlsx-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Maybe related - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir#:~:text=The%20asterisk%20wildcard%20always%20uses%20short%20file%20name%20mapping%2C%20so%20you%20might%20get%20unexpected%20results.%20For%20example%2C%20the%20following%20directory%20contains%20two%20files%20(t.txt2%20and%20t97.txt)%3A   Short names for files with xlsx extension end with ".XLS"

Comment: @braX Thank you for that suggestion. Maybe I misunderstand something, but using `"*.xls?"` og `"*.xls*"` as a file filter as suggested in the upvoted answer does not solve the problem. I still receive `5` as result.

Comment: @MichaelWycisk You are [supposed to](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140313-00/?p=1513).

Comment: @GSerg - that was the link I was looking for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir#:~:text=The%20asterisk%20wildcard%20always%20uses%20short%20file%20name%20mapping%2C%20so%20you%20might%20get%20unexpected%20results.%20For%20example%2C%20the%20following%20directory%20contains%20two%20files%20(t.txt2%20and%20t97.txt)%3A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir#:%7E:text=The%20asterisk%20wildcard%20always%20uses%20short%20file%20name%20mapping%2C%20so%20you%20might%20get%20unexpected%20results.%20For%20example%2C%20the%20following%20directory%20contains%20two%20files%20(t.txt2%20and%20t97.txt)%3A)

> The asterisk wildcard always uses short file name mapping, so you
> might get unexpected results.

Windows short name for files with (eg) "xlsx"/"xlsm"/etc extension all
end with ".XLS"

More-detailed overview at GSerg's link in the comments above.

Comment: Thank you! So the issue is the same as described in the link from @GSerg. Is there any more elegant solution then adding something like `If Right(vFile, 3) = "xls" Then` in the `While/Wend` loop?

Comment: You could use `If vFile Like sFileType Then` and I guess that would filter out the false positives?

Comment: Check this out: https://vmlogger.com/excel/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

Toward the bottom of the page you can click a button named 'Download File Manager' and download an Excel file that will do the work for you.